# Why was my server 2003 question moved to superuser.com?

Tags: discussion

This question

https://serverfault.com/questions/213602/why-would-a-2tb-drive-say-half-its-space-is-used-when-it-isnt-closed

was moved to superuser.com, and I don't know why.

It's an O/S question about a windows 2003 server, and it seems completely pertinent to serverfault.com. The people most likely to be able to answer it are people who work with large disks and windows 2003. (A server operating system)

Can people explain to me why this was moved.

**Update**

So - It turns out that the disk is probably faulty. I was initially confused by the fact that the disk size had been halved to 1TB, and I felt this was an issue with Server 2003. I was wrong about this. I really believed that this was a server issue and not something that applied to any generic operating system.

Also - The FAQ has changed since I last read it. That whole "applies to any computer" subrule is new to me.

The point has been made here that I didn't provide enough information. I provided the information I had, and would have been happy to provide extra information as it was asked. I don't think I should be punished for not knowing where to look and what information to initially provide.

None of this was enough. The question was moved (I believed incorrectly), and when asking why it was moved, I was told that the reason was because "people voted for it to be moved". This was just hugely frustrating. After the move, and then the snotty responses (it was moved because we said so), I was left feeling that I was not welcome at serverfault.com.

I realise that I'm not a big user of serverfault, and my lack of admin knowledge may make me a noob, but to come to this place and be told that I'm not welcome is very upsetting. I know you don't really care about this, and you're more invested in making the place a proper forum for proper administrators, but the attitude towards my question, a question I asked in good faith, is wrong.

Don't know where I'm going with this. I know that serverfault is not the right place for me now. I guess I still have google. I think an ask/answer community should be better than this.

Comment: Why are you taking it *personally*?  Most times, things are moved if we (more than one) think you'll have a better chance of having your question answered on a sister site, which it was..so not really sure why you had/have a problem with it.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I don't tend to *decide* what things to take personally. The thing that upset me most was the double "5 people voted to move it there" brushoff.

Comment: Without sounding like Dr. Phil, you are in complete control of how you decide to take things.

Comment: I voted to move because I felt that this wasn't a network administration question - this problem would occur regardless of whether this windows 2003 server was a domain controller at the heart of a 50,000 user network or a copy you'd downloaded from MSDN and stuck on an old laptop for LOLs. I also felt that this wasn't an OS dependant question and even if it was, Operating system is not the defining point of where a question should belong. This is nothing to do with you being welcome (you are) or unwelcome *and everything to do with the contents of that particular question*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Honestly, I wouldn't get too worked up about a single question.

I don't think anyone voted to move the question because they don't like you or your question, they just felt that the question was a better fit on a different site.

The goal is to get answers -- and moving the question to the appropriate site helps that happen!

Answer (score 6):

The question has little to do with system administration. It sounds like a hardware problem. The OS is completely irrelevant, there's also home users and individual workstations running "server" OSes, that doesn't automatically make the question subject related to systems administration.

Super User's scope includes individual computers with hardware problems. Since the questions seems to point to consumer grade hardware issues, it's fits in SU's scope.

I understand how this might be confusing to you; other people have found themselves in similar situations. There's a fellow with a question about using a Mac Mini as a "server" who went through the same discussion not long ago.

In response to your update. Nobody told you that you weren't welcome here when your question was moved. Please see the FAQ with regards to collaborative editing and organizing of questions. Getting upset and accusing us of not caring is irrational and unprofessional (what would your boss think/say if he/she saw all of this?). This is not a forum, it's a Q&A site; please see the FAQ for details. This site is for professional administrators, again it's in the FAQ. If these are things you don't like about the site: "this may not be the site for you" (again, from the FAQ). I apologize if this is terse, but the site is what it is.

Answer (score 5):

Because 5 different users voted to move it there, that's how this site works.

Comment: OK - So why did you vote to move it to superuser?

Comment: Because 5 different users voted to move it there.

Comment: That's not at all helpful.

Comment: Because you gave us very little information at all to work off and your problem is almost certainly generic, that it's on a server of some sort is unlikely to be part of the issue.

Comment: @seanyboy - I voted to send it to SU because I thought your most likely to get a better and quicker answer over there.

Comment: @chopper3 I think when someone writes up a long meta post in good faith they probably should be extended the courtesy of a more detailed response...

Comment: @Jeff, it wasn't long originally, it was two sentence before his edit, the reason it was migrated was because 4 people before me thought it was better moved. I can't speak for those four people but the reason it was migrated was simply "because 5 different users voted". Do we really need to change the 'move' form to include justifications for people who write a bad question then put oceans more time into boohoo'ing about it on meta than they did into the original question or even the original whine? If so that's not mod'ing it's babysitting and I don't have time to wipe oversensitive chins.

Comment: So are you saying you would vote to move any question that had 4 move votes already?

Answer (score 5):

Had I seen that question before it was moved I would also have voted to move it. It displays a lack of knowledge and understanding that should be expected of a professional system administrator, so is an inappropriate question for SF. Simply working with a server OS does NOT mean you qualify as an IT professional. Please read the FAQ.

In your edit to this question you state "It turns out that the disk is probably faulty". A professional would have tested that first, certainly before asking a question such as yours, and would be able to state that the drive is either faulty or not. No "probably" about it.